# Django tests with selenium not loading fixtures

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

I am setting up functional testing using Selenium for a Django website. I have a fixture file (`users/fixtures/users.json`) and am using it in the functional tests in another app (`accounts`). When running the tests, I also run my development server to accept requests from Selenium browser automation; I run `./manage.py test` and `./manage.py runserver` on the same settings module so that both have the credentials for the same database.

My `accounts` tests are failing to load the `users` fixture:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class AccountCreationTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['users']

    # Tests depending on user login follow.
    # These tests are run via Selenium for browser automation.
```

These tests succeed when I manually load the fixtures into the test database via the command line, but they fail otherwise, so I know they are making use of the fixture data when it is present in the database, and I also know that they are failing to load the test fixtures.

To recap: I am running `./manage.py test` and `./manage.py runserver` on the same settings module that defines the test database access credentials. If the fixtures are being loaded into the test database, that data should be available to tests when they run via Selenium.

What am I missing?

Edit 1: For context, I am using Django 1.8. Also, I'm using Selenium to automate PhantomJS so that the tests can run faster.

Edit 2: I just did a more thorough reading of Django docs and found two issues that I'm running into.

First issue: Django tests [automatically prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#test) the database name with `test_`, so you have to make sure that your test server and your Django tests are using the same database by name, like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'NAME': "test_db_name",
    'TEST': {
        'NAME': "test_db_name"
    }
}
```

Second issue: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) explain that Django destroys test databases between test runs. This will cause the development server to fail because it requires the presence of a database. Django 1.8 introduced the `--keepdb` option for the test runner that will keep the database instance around between tests. While this flag does allow the server to run on the test database, I still cannot seem to get the fixtures to load into that database. This could be caused by the use of the new flag, which does significantly modify the behavior of tests in terms of how they load the test database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django testing with Selenium can be touchy. To recap, there are three main issues you have to deal with to get tests like this to work:

1) Selenium needs a running Django server to bounce requests off of.

2) Your running Django server should be connected to the test database.

3) TestCase tests run in a transaction. Since the running Django server can't see into the test case's transaction, any fixtures you load will be completely invisible/inaccessible to Selenium (source: [Lara's link, qris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041315/how-to-have-django-test-case-and-selenium-server-use-same-database)).

Solution:
To solve the first two problems, you need a testing-specific settings file. In it, you need to define a default database that points to your testing database, and you need to give your testing database's settings so that the names match (See the example in my question). When you plan to run your tests, you need to run a Django development server and your tests using the testing settings file.

To solve the third problem, use `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`. `TransactionTestCase` is meant to give developers finer control over transaction behavior during testing, so it doesn't automatically run everything inside of a transaction (which, in turn, gives the running server instance access to fixtures). Even though this isn't exactly what we're trying to do in this case, the result is that the tests work and clean up after themselves automatically.

Note: You should probably consider separating black-box and white-box tests from each other. This keeps your Django tests "vanilla" so future developers don't have to waste as much time figuring out why Django documentation doesn't seem to apply in all cases. It also decouples functional tests from the unit tests, which is good in cases where a developer on your team doesn't have access to Selenium (or a compatible version of Selenium) on their machine, or when you want to run only the unit tests or functional tests, but not both. You would need to manually set up your testing environment to suit your needs, but I believe this would keep the testing code cleaner in the long run.

Thanks to Lara for pointing me in the right direction on this.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had the same problem and, I noticed that somehow, Django Test Case and Selenium don't use the same database. Why?  I have no clue!

I think is something about tearDown and Setup ... Anyway, I think you can solve your problem here -> [How to have Django test case and Selenium server use same database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041315/how-to-have-django-test-case-and-selenium-server-use-same-database)

Comment: This looks like it might work (The connection to the in-memory database might persist even if the database itself is destroyed and created between each test run). I'll try this out and see if I can't get my use case to work.