# Configure Selenium use pytest test database in django app so that CI is supported

Tags: python, django, selenium, pytest, gitlab-ci

I am running a dockerized django app and I am running selenium tests using pytest.

It seems like pytest is using a different database for running tests than my development app. That means I can't use fixtures (because fixtures are created in a different db).

I am confused on three levels:

Firstly, I see many tutorials using fixtures with selenium and pytest. So that means selenium is using the testdatabase.

Secondly according to this answer pytest has to use the same testdatabase as my develompent app ([Django tests with selenium not loading fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477051/))

Thirdly according to django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/ a test db is created before every testrun and then destroyed.

That bears the following trouble for me: I am running my selenium tests also within a CI pipeline. So I need to be able to create fixtures or instances in the db during execution. I have read that selenium shouldn't be used for model tests. Ok, but almost all my views are protected so I need to login, so I need a user, so I need a model.

Thus, my question: How can I run pytest with selenium using the same database so that fixtures are supported, which is also transportable to an automatic pipeline?

I provide code to be more clear (creating a user here was for testing if my fixture actually work):

My test:

```
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
    def test_login(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin',
                                      password='mylongpassword',
                                      )

        print(User.objects.count())

        browser.get('http://django:8000/admin')
        username_input = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        pass_input = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        username_input.send_keys('admin')
        pass_input.send_keys('mylongpassword')

        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
        assert browser.current_url == 'http://django:8000/admin/'
```

My setup

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def setup(self):
        User = get_user_model()

        User.objects.create_superuser(username='admin2',
                                      password='mylongpassword2')
        global browser
        browser = webdriver.Remote(
         command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
         desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )
        yield
        browser.quit()
```

And on top of that, if I use the following fixture and pass it to my tests I still can't authentiate **even though my user is created and I am connecting to the same database as my running app** (printing it in the terminal gives me the same user output as in shell mode in my app):

```
    @pytest.fixture()
    def django_db_setup(self):
        settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
            'HOST': 'postgres',
            'NAME': 'mywebsite',  # my dedicated test database (!)
            'PORT': '5432',
            'USER':  'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to make db fixture for your test, pytest does it for you.

You just have to use pytest db fixture for it

Pytest doesn't support you to run the test on production/main DB if you are using pytest-django. 
There is a better approach to solve this issue.

- [Pytest DB resolve method](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html)
- This says that whenever you run the test with a marker `@pytest.mark.django_db`, tests are run on another newly created db with name `test_your production_db_name`.
- So if your db name is `hello`, pytest will create a new db called `test_hello` and runs tests on it

Comment: Thank you Nithin for your response! Adding extra configuration to specify a db was rather for debugging. The problem is that pytest and selenium use different db. I solved the problem by running my tests not against http://django:8000 but with a live_server_url. Like this pytest and selenium use the same db