# How to use the django test's database with Selenium?

Tags: django, selenium, testing, functional-testing

I am testing my django app with django TestCase class. For unit tests and integrations tests I encountered no problem with the database django create then destroy for the tests. But now i want to do some functional test using selenium. The problem is that selenium seem to not be able to access the db. Here is the test code of my test :

```
class HostTest(LiveServerTestCase, TestCase):


    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

        # Setting up temporary test database

        # Setting up products
        self.product1 = Product.objects.create(
            id=1,
            name="apple",
            url="apple_url",
            nutriscore="A",
            img_url="apple_img_url",
            kcal=101,
            fat=201,
            protein=301,
            sugar=401,
        )


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def test_new_user_reserach_and_add_favorite(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.live_server_url)
        self.assertIn("Accueil", driver.title)

        search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("product_searched")
        search_bar.send_keys("apple")
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.assertIn("Recherche", driver.title)

        product = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-presentation')
```

For this I have an error at the last line, and the error is long but its basically tell me that selenium cant find the element. I tried to print product1 in the test and it work. That why I'm pretty sure that the problem is with Selenium.

Here is the code of my view :

```
def product_research(request):
    no_repetition_result = []
    vectors = SearchVector('name', weight='A') + SearchVector('category__name', weight='B')
    query = SearchQuery(f'{request.GET.get("product_searched")}')

    research_result = Product.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).order_by('-rank')

    for product in research_result:
        if product not in no_repetition_result:
            no_repetition_result.append(product)

    context = {
        "results": no_repetition_result,
    }
    request.session['research_parameter'] = request.GET.get("product_searched")
    return render(request, 'main_site/product_research.html', context)
```

And the html code charged to make appear the product on my web page :

```
<div class="row">
    {% for product in results %}
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"
            <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
                <a class="col product-presentation text-center" href="{% url 'main_site:product' product.id %}">
                    <img class="substitution-product-img" src="{{ product.img_url }}">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note: When I take a look at the code of the page selenium open while testing, I dont see any product.

Comment: While your test starts, you can hard stop the test before it can complete and django wouldn't be able to destroy the db, then you can try logging into the db and check if the data is being created correctly or not. Just to make sure....

Comment: @ArunT I tested and my db create but there is nothing inside. So now I just have so much more questions. Why my other tests works ? Why can I print the product if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: You will have to put a print statement in this particular test after the test data creation and once you see that print statement in your terminal then you can hard stop the test and inspect what is in your db.

Comment: @ArunT I cant do that, I didn't found a way to stop the test in a particular moment of the test. I use the command ```py .\manage.py test --keepdb```

Comment: If you follow the above direction on putting a print statement in the line where you want to terminate and then terminate the process by using Ctrl + C, u will be able to stop the test

Comment: When I use ctrl + c (no matter when) it destroy the database then raise a KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: You could put a delay of say 5 mins and then check the db during that time?

Comment: Already tried, and still empty :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041315/how-to-have-django-test-case-and-selenium-server-use-same-database)

This is the same problem that you are facing and has a clean explanation.

Comment: Ok so the problem for me (I understood it while reading the post you provided) was my test class inherited from TestCase. But with Selenium, you have to make it inherit from TransactionTestCase.

Comment: Yes, if you remove TestCase from this line,`class HostTest(LiveServerTestCase, TestCase):`  then it should work.